Solve $\left| 2x-5 \right| \leq \left|x+4 \right|$

Solve $\left| 2x-5 \right| \leq \left|x+4 \right|$

If both are positive: $2x-5 \leq x+4 \Rightarrow x \leq 9$
If one is negative: $2x-5 \leq -(x+4) \Rightarrow 2x-5 \leq -x-4 \Rightarrow x \leq \frac{1}{3}$
This turned out to be wrong. However, if I put the negative sign on the other side, I get the correct answer: $-(2x-5) \leq x+4 \Rightarrow -2x+5 \leq x+4 \Rightarrow x \geq \frac{1}{3}$
Why?
I know $|x|=|y|$ means $x=y$ and $x=-y; -x=y$.
But in this problem when $|x| \leq |y|$, it means $-x \leq y$. Why can't the other way $x \leq -y$ work?

You can raise both sides to the second power.

No I want to understand my question.

It would be better to consider four cases: 1) $2x-5 \ge 0, x+4 \ge 0$ 2) $2x-5 \ge 0, x+4<0$ 3) $2x-5<0, x+4 \ge 0$ 4) $2x-5<0, x+4<0$.

We need $0\le (x+4)^2-(2x-5)^2=(3x-1)(9-x).$  Hence $1/3\le x\le 9.$ In this way we avoid considering cases.

You should consider cases determined by the points at which the absolute value expressions change signs.
By definition, $|x|$ is the distance of $x$ from $0$.  If $x \geq 0$, then $|x| = x - 0 = x$.  If $x < 0$, $|x| = 0 - x = -x$.  Therefore,
$$|x| = \begin{cases}
x & \text{if $x \geq 0$}\\
-x & \text{if $x < 0$}
\end{cases}
$$
Observe that $2x - 5 \geq 0 \iff x \geq 5/2$.  Hence,
$$|2x - 5| = \begin{cases}
2x - 5 & \text{if $x \geq 5/2$}\\
-2x + 5 & \text{if $x < 5/2$}
\end{cases}
$$
Observe that $x + 4 \geq 0 \iff x \geq -4$.  Hence,
$$|x + 4| = \begin{cases}
x + 4 & \text{if $x \geq -4$}\\
-x - 4 & \text{if $x < -4$}
\end{cases}
$$
We have three cases to consider: $x \geq 5/2$, $-4 \leq x < 5/2$, and $x < -4$.
Case 1: $x \geq 5/2$
Then $|2x - 5| = 2x - 5$ and $|x + 4| = x + 4$.  Hence,
\begin{align*}
|2x - 5| & \leq |x + 4|\\
2x - 5 & \leq x + 4\\
x & \leq 9
\end{align*}
Therefore, the inequality is satisfied for $5/2 \leq x \leq 9$.
Case 2: $-4 \leq x < 5/2$
Then $|2x - 5| = -2x + 5$ and $|x + 4| = x + 4$.  Thus,
\begin{align*}
|2x - 5| & \leq |x + 4|\\
2x + 5 & \leq x + 4\\
1 & \leq 3x\\
\frac{1}{3} & \leq x
\end{align*}
Therefore, the inequality is also satisfied if $1/3 \leq x < 5/2$.
Case 3: $x < -4$.
Then $|2x - 5| = -2x + 5$ and $|x + 4| = -x - 4$.  Therefore,
\begin{align*}
|2x - 5| & \leq |x + 4|\\
-2x + 5 & \leq -x - 4\\
9 & \leq x
\end{align*}
However, $x < -4$, so it is not possible for $x \geq 9$.  Therefore, there are no solutions in this case.
Conclusion: The solution set of the inequality $|2x - 5| \leq |x + 4|$ is $S = [1/3, 9]$.
Notice that is not possible for $x + 4 < 0$ and $2x - 5 \geq 0$ simultaneously since that would imply $x < -4$ and $x \geq 5/2$.  That was the case that did not work for you.

When you have equality and one is negative the contents of $x=-y$ and $-x=y$ are the same. If $y$ was the negative one, you would write $x=-y$ to get an equality of nonnegative quantities and the other for $x$ being negative.
So you didn't pay attention to which one was negative, you just said one of them was negative.
But with the inequality, if $x$ is the negative one, then you have $-x \leq y$. Compare that to $y$ being the negative one giving $x \leq -y$. They are off by a multiplication by $-1$ which unlike the equality flips the direction of the inequality.

In $a>b$, if I multiply both sides by $-1$, then the inequality becomes $-a<-b$. This is intuitively obvious on the number line. But in my problem here, I am only assigning one side of the inequality the negative sign, not both. So this is where I'm confused.

You have two different inequalities depending on which one is negative. You tried the one with $x+4$ was negative and $2x-5$ was positive. Then after you simplify that, you get $x \leq 1/3$ but then when you plug that back in you see that assumption didn't hold. You had to do the other way around.

You wrote this: "But in this problem when $|x|≤|y|$, it means $−x≤y$. Why can't the other way $x≤−y$ work?" which is not quite the right question to ask.  You need both, but they only work in particular situations -- you need to check $-x\leq y$, but that situation is only valid when $x$ is negative and $y$ is positive (so if the answer you get contradicts that, it has to go away); and similarly you need to check $x \leq -y$ but again double-check your result to make sure $x$ is positive and $y$ is negative.  So the result you found of $x\leq \frac13$ disappears because you set it up with $2x-5$ positive (since you left that absolute value the same) and $x+4$ negative (since you changed that sign for the absolute value) -- but those signs aren't right (on that range $2x-5$ is always negative).


I know $|x|=|y|$ means $x=y$ and $x=-y; -x=y$.

No, $$|x|=|y|$$ just means that $x$ equals $y$ or $-y.$

but when $|x| \leq |y|$ and one is negative, it means $-x \leq y.$ Why
can't the other way $x \leq -y$ work?

No, when $$|x| \leq |y|\quad \text{and $x$ and $y$ are not both positive},$$ then we have that $$x \leq -y\quad\text{or}\quad -x\leq y\quad\text{or}\quad -x\leq -y.$$
(That is, $$|x| \leq |y|\iff\\ x\le y\quad\text{or}\quad x \leq -y\quad\text{or}\quad -x\leq y\quad\text{or}\quad -x\leq -y.)$$


Solve $\left| 2x-5 \right| \leq \left|x+4 \right|.$


The above equivalence follows your intended method to obtain the required solution.

You can solve this with a change of variables.
Try $u = x + 4$, so $x = u - 4$.
$$ |2u-13| \le |u| $$
These two curves intersect at:

$2u - 13 = u$
$2u - 13 = -u$

In the first, $u = 13$, in the second, $u = \frac{13}{3}$.
Both of these functions are continuous, so the comparison can only flip when the curves pass through each other, i.e. at these two points. Intuitively, $|2u-13|$ is much steeper than $|u|$ so we would expect it to be true in the middle and false at both ends, but let's confirm to make sure.

Test at $u=0$. $|2*0 - 13| > |0|$.
Test at $u=10$. $|2*10-13| < |10|$.
Test at $u=100$. $|2*100-13| > |100|$.

So, this holds when $\frac{13}{3} \le u \le 13$.
Substituting back in for $x$, $\frac{1}{3} \le x \le 9$.
As a quick check to make sure we didn't mess anything up.

Test at $x=0$, $|2*0 - 5| > |0 + 4|$.
Test at $x=\frac{1}{3}$, $|2*\frac{1}{3} - 5| = |\frac{1}{3} + 4|$. Yes both sides are $4+\frac{1}{3}$.
Test at $x=1$, $|2*1 - 5| < |1 + 4|$.
Test at $x=9$, $|2*9 - 5| = |9 + 4|$. Yes, both sides are 13.
Test at $x=10$, $|2*10 - 5| > |10 + 4|$ Yes, $15 > 14$.


Once again, one may expand a little, demanding that the planar distance from $(x,y)$  to $(-4,0)$  be double the distance from $(x,y)$ to  $( \frac{5}{2},0)$   for which the solution set is this genuine circle
The distance formula in the plane gives us
$$  \sqrt{(x+4)^2 + y^2}  = 2 \sqrt{(x- \frac{5}{2})^2  + y^2}  $$
square both sides and clean up


Here is another approach by drawing the graph of $y=|2x-5|$ and $y=|x+4|$:
Note that the vertex of the graph of $y=|2x-5|$ is $x=2.5$, and from this point we draw two half-lines with slopes of $2$ and $-2$. Similarly, the vertex of $y=|x+4|$ is $x=-4$, and we should draw to half-lines with slopes of $1$ and $-1$. Here is the graph:

Now we want the $x$ values such that $\left| 2x-5 \right| \leq \left|x+4 \right|$, in other words we are looking for the case where the blue graph is on or above the red graph. We find the intersection of the right half line of the blue graph ($y=x+4$) with the red graph:
$$x+4=2x-5\;\;\text{and}\;\;x+4=-(2x-5)\;\;\Rightarrow\; x=9\;,\;x=\dfrac13$$
Hence, $\dfrac13\le x\le9$.
Note that you don't need a graphing calculator for this problem. In fact, one can visualize the graphs without even drawing them.

Notice that $|a|\le|b|$ is equivalent to $a^2\le b^2$, for real numbers $a$, $b$.
So the following inequalities are equivalent to each other:
\begin{align*}
|2x-5| &\le |x+4| \\
(2x-5)^2 &\le (x+4)^2 \\
(2x-5)^2 - (x+4)^2 \le 0 \\
(3x-1)(x-9) \le 0 
\end{align*}
The product is negative iff one of them is positive and the other one is negative. So we have two possibilities:

$x\ge\frac13$ and $x\le9$;
$x\le\frac13$ and $x\ge9$.

But there are no numbers fulfilling the conditions in the second bullet point. So we are left with $\frac13\le x\le 9$.
